# Android: Thread pausing intermittently

Tags: android, multithreading, android-canvas, surfaceview, trace

having some trouble with a Thread (CanvasThread) that is intermittently pausing at random points within my application. Everything else in the app continues to function as necessary, it's simply this thread that randomly blocks out for some reason and doesn't draw anything new to the screen. I noticed that Surface.lockCanvasNative() seems to be the last function called before the block, and the first one returned after. In a pattern as such:

```
Surface.lockCanvasNative (Landroid/graphics/Rect)Landroid/graphics/Canvas; @ 26,560 msec  ____
Surface.lockCanvasNative (Landroid/graphics/Rect)Landroid/graphics/Canvas; @ 40,471 msec  ____|

Surface.lockCanvasNative (Landroid/graphics/Rect)Landroid/graphics/Canvas; @ 40,629 msec  ____
Surface.lockCanvasNative (Landroid/graphics/Rect)Landroid/graphics/Canvas; @ 54,516 msec  ____|
```

This is evident with the traceview below:
[image: traceview of frozen thread]

I have been using the `CanvasThread.run()` below if it helps:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    boolean tellRendererSurfaceChanged = true;

    /*
     * This is our main activity thread's loop, we go until
     * asked to quit.
     */
    while (!mDone) {
        /*
         *  Update the asynchronous state (window size)
         */
        int w;
        int h;
        synchronized (this) {
            // If the user has set a runnable to run in this thread,
            // execute it and record the amount of time it takes to 
            // run.
            if (mEvent != null) {
                mEvent.run();
            }

            if(needToWait()) {
                while (needToWait()) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    }
                }
            }
            if (mDone) {
                break;
            }
            tellRendererSurfaceChanged = mSizeChanged;
            w = mWidth;
            h = mHeight;
            mSizeChanged = false;
        }


        if (tellRendererSurfaceChanged) {
            mRenderer.sizeChanged(w, h);
            tellRendererSurfaceChanged = false;
        }

        if ((w > 0) && (h > 0)) {
            // Get ready to draw.
            // We record both lockCanvas() and unlockCanvasAndPost()
            // as part of "page flip" time because either may block
            // until the previous frame is complete.

            Canvas canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

            if (canvas != null) {
                // Draw a frame!
                mRenderer.drawFrame(canvas);                        
                mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

                //CanvasTestActivity._isAsyncGoTime = true;    
            }
            else{
                Log.v("CanvasSurfaceView.CanvasThread", "canvas == null");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just let me know if I can provide any other useful information. I'm simply looking for clues as to why my thread might be blocking at this point? Thanks for any help in advance!

I've since narrowed the block down to `mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);` I inserted a log before and after this call and the one after is not logged after app is frozen; but the log before is last logged event on this thread. It's not pausing or using a null canvas either, because I threw in logs for those instances as well; which are not logged even once until app is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have since figured out my problem. I'm not sure why but because I had accidentally forgot to fully comment out an earlier asyncTask(), thus had two doing roughly the same tasks and obviously struggling to do so with the same variables and such. Thanks for your pointers, but simply another careless mistake on my part I guess.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this could be the reason, but under SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(), it warns that,

> If you call this repeatedly when the
>   Surface is not ready (before
>   Callback.surfaceCreated or after
>   Callback.surfaceDestroyed), your calls
>   will be throttled to a slow rate in
>   order to avoid consuming CPU.
>
> If null is not returned, this function
>   internally holds a lock until the
>   corresponding
>   unlockCanvasAndPost(Canvas) call,
>   preventing SurfaceView from creating,
>   destroying, or modifying the surface
>   while it is being drawn. This can be
>   more convenient than accessing the
>   Surface directly, as you do not need
>   to do special synchronization with a
>   drawing thread in
>   Callback.surfaceDestroyed.

I'm not sure what the threshold is when the CPU starts throttling. How many threads are refreshing the canvas?

btw,

```
if(needToWait()) {
                while (needToWait()) {
```

is redundant

Comment: yeah in this case I could've left out the `if(needToWat())`. I've looked into this, and I've logged all abnormal surface activity (created, destroyed, paused, whatever...) and nothing abnormal happens during the freeze, except that unlockCanvasAndPost() does not actually unlock and post the canvas to the screen. As far as it holding a lock until the corresponding `unlockCanvasAndPost(Canvas)` is concerned, that's just common sense isn't it? This simply prevents manipulation between lock and unlock. That doesn't mean lock won't unlock it when called to unlock?